# Passing a php session variable to HTML Select tag and show from the available list as the selected value

Tags: php, html

Currently I have a HTML select tag with some options available. For that Select tag I need to pass a session  variable and show as the selected value. Kindly provide your support to achieve this task.

```
<?php

 session_start()

 //Variable need to show in Select tag
 //Session value Equals to - Junior Executive Assistant
 $_SESSION['Designation'];


?>

<select id="designation" class="form-control" name="designation" required> 

    <option value="Banking Trainee">Banking Trainee</option>
    <option value="Junior Executive Assistant">Junior Executive Assistant</option>
    <option value="Junior Executive Officer">Junior Executive Officer</option>
    <option value="Executive officer">Executive officer</option>
    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
    <option value="Senior Manager">Senior Manager</option>
    <option value="Chief Manager">Chief Managerr</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `session_start()` also is needed on top of your page

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Question modified and answer received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a check to each of your select options to see if its value matches the value in `$_SESSION['Designation']` and if so, set the `selected` attribute on that option. For example:

```
<option value="Banking Trainee"<?php echo $_SESSION['Designation'] == 'Banking Trainee' ? ' selected' : ''; ?> >Banking Trainee</option>
```

For the other options you would change the comparison string appropriately.

If you have PHP short tags enabled, you can simplify the code slightly by using `<?=` in place of `<?php echo` e.g.

```
<option value="Banking Trainee"<?= $_SESSION['Designation'] == 'Banking Trainee' ? ' selected' : '' ?> >Banking Trainee</option>
```